# How to print a custom warning at the *end* of a Puppet run?

Tags: puppet

Verbose Puppet runs are verbose. To make sure the user notices a [custom warning message](https://github.com/l0b0/root/blob/82ad23d90c7a42d482eb67135795e33a94da5062/modules/network_manager/manifests/init.pp#L20), it would be good to print it only at the *end* of the run. Is this possible without major breakage of the Puppet execution model?

Comment: I would try to move the error message(s) to a sub class, then use [Run Stages](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_run_stages.html) to run it as the last one.

Comment: @FranklinPiat If you could provide a working example, that would make for a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
notify{"That's all folks!": }
```

There are a few ways you could do this. You could make your init.pp look like:

```
class foo {
    class  { '::foo::begin': }
    class  { '::foo::end': require => Class['::foo::begin']  }
}
```

Or you could define custom run stages which is really up to you how you define it. Here's the link:

https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_run_stages.html

Comment: Do you have a working example? I already know how to use `notify`, it's the whole "make it run last" part that is actually the problem.

Comment: sure, edited my answer

Comment: I was really hoping for an example where the message is printed at the end of the **Puppet run**. The example does not demonstrate this.